# Add string to existing row separated by comma in sql

Tags: sql, database, sequelpro

```
id  value
1   a
2   b   
3   c
```

How do i add second value 'z' to id=1 (separated by comma)?

```
id  value
1   a,z
2   b   
3   c
```

and how to remove the 'z' now if i have that final table?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `update`:

```
update t
    set value = concat(value, ',z')
    where id = 1;
```

Comment: will it be the same result as `set value = 'a, z'` as well?

Comment: @fauxxi . . . Minus the space and assuming that the existing value is `'a'`.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your secondary question, yes.

If you run `Select value from table where id = 1` it will return `a,z`. that means that if you are going to use it again in queries, you will quite possibly need to utilize a `Split()` type function, dependent on what you're doing with it.

Answer (score 0):

The best and simplest way to do this is the following query according to me :

update table1 set value = concat(value,'z') where id = 1

where : Table1 is the name of your table.